# How to create a gui in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to create a gui in java which will take a string from a user and then user will click on submit button.On clicking the submit button,the user will do some processing on the string and then give output on screen(gui).

I have written the following code till now but when I run this code,it doesn't give any output.

```java
public class userinterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   
    public userinterface() {
        initComponents();
    }
                   
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    
    public void show() {
        String str = jTextField1.getText();
                        
        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("You clicked the button,str");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new userinterface().setVisible(true);
                userinterface obj = new userinterface();
                obj.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Please tell me where am I doing wrong ? How can I make the output display on gui screen?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the class even compile? You seem to call this method: `initComponents()` without the class having the method. Have you gone through the [Oracle Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)? The [basic Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)?

Comment: yes,class compiles(actually I have removed some auto-generated code).The problem must be in these two functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you've overridden the essential method `show()` without realizing it, and this prevents the JFrame from displaying. Change the name of this method to something different:

```
public void myShow() {
  // String str = jTextField1.getText(); // not useful

  jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Execute when button is pressed
        System.out.println("You clicked the button,str");
     }
  });
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        // new userinterface().setVisible(true);
        userinterface obj = new userinterface();
        // obj.show();
        obj.myShow();
        obj.setVisible(true);
     }
  });
}
```

This is another reason that we all should strive not to extend classes unless absolutely necessary, since doing so can occasionally cause very difficult to debug errors.

I was able to debug this by placing println's throughout your code and seeing that show() was being called even when it wasn't explicitly being called by me.

Comment: Any decent IDE will show you an icon in the sidebar indicating you overrode something of the super-class, which should ring a bell. But I do agree with your remark about not having to extend the Swing component classes unless you have a very good reason

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("this is GUI boi");

frame.setSize(500, 500);
panel.add(label);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

1. you have to instantiate all the gui components
2. you have to call the `setVisible()` method of the JFrame
3. you have to set a width and height of the JFrame
4. you have add the components to a parent component(like a label to a panel and that panel to a frame)